# How to open Chrome or Mozilla window when clicking a link in Internet Explorer(IE)?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, google-chrome, mozilla

Is there a possible way to do that?

Do i have to insert a property inside some  attribute?

Comment: No, you can't do that.

Comment: The operating system decides how to handle links of a given type. If it's an HTTP link, the user's favourite browser will handle it. You can't force the user to use the software of your choice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Launch application from a browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057576/launch-application-from-a-browser)

Comment: These are both correct.  The only close suggestion is to detect the browser and suggest that they use a different (more modern) one.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723244/javascript-code-to-force-html-page-to-open-in-chrome-browser. The answer from AlanFoster might be what you're trying to do. Note that this might work in an intranet environment, where you have some control over what programs the user has installed; but this is not a practical idea over the Internet. Also, some organizations disable ActiveX even on their intranet for security reasons.