# Open link from IE to Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer, hyperlink

Hi maybe this is too easy to ask but i am just thinking if this is possible.
For example i have a button that im a using Internet Explorer then i want its link to Open using Google Chrome? Is this possible? I am using the code below. From Internet Explorer to Chrome browser

```
$("#myBtn").click(function(){               
       window.open('https://facebook.com');
 });
```

I have tried the above code using Internet Explorer but as expected the link open in same Internet Explorer. I want to open it in chrome

Comment: A little search !!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723244/javascript-code-to-force-html-page-to-open-in-chrome-browser

Comment: hi  in this sample it says it will open chrome but how can i add the url or site that it will  open

Answer (score 1):

Nope, not possible.

You can't specify what program to use in either HTML or JavaScript, to open an url.

Technically, in IE ActiveX Objects *could* open a certain program, assuming ActiveX isn't blocked, *and* you know the *exact* path to the application.
So, that still wouldn't work in most cases.