# Pop up a child chrome window from parent IE window

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to pop up a different browser from that of a parent?

Ex: A parent window "IE" will pop up a new "chrome (or any other window)"

The problem i have is that the "window.opener.callback" javascript functions gives me an error on IE, but not on any other browser type.

Thanks!

Comment: Wait, you mean you want to open chrome if they're visiting on IE? No, not possible, thank god.

Comment: I am afraid yes.. thanks for the input brother.

Comment: While I understand the frustration of browsers having different capabilities, being able to arbitrarily run a program via javascript is one of the worst things I could imagine. Unfortunately, you'll just need to write an IE workaround (`if (!window.opener.callback) { //ie specific code } else { //normal browser code }`) - the way we've done for years :). Alternatively, you could just display a message to the user saying your site does not support their browser.

Comment: There are other questions similar to this. You can use Activex. but  that depends on the policy of your organization. because most of the cases activex are blocked. The this stackoverflow  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723244/javascript-code-to-force-html-page-to-open-in-chrome-browser)